# how to create given horizontal drop down menu with Ul and li element using html and css

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am new in HTML and css ,can Anybody give me some idea

[image]

Comment: Have you search it on internet. You can find easily if you tried.

Comment: I'm also very new to HTML and css. I found this website very helpful:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp

The second element, <select> will give you drop down lists.

Comment: I don't want it in hover, i want it dropdown ,i want it with ul and li element only

Answer (score 1):

Try This

HTML

```
<div class='lst'>
    <label for="select1">Label1</label>
    <select id="select1"> 
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option></select>
</div>

<div class='lst'>
    <label for="select2">Label2</label>
    <select id="select1"><option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option><select>
</div>

<div class='lst'>
    <label for="select3">Label3</label>
    <select id="select3"><option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option><select>
</div>

<div class='lst'>
    <label for="select3">Label3</label>
    <select id="select3"><option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option><select>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 div.lst {
     float: left;   
     margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
    }

    div.lst label {
     display: block;   
    }
```

You can view demo here http://jsfiddle.net/tenigada/Z5hAm/15/

Answer (score 0):

A select tag will give you a drop down list. Here is an example:

```
<select> 
<option>Option1</option>
<option>Option2</option>
<option>Option3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this its may helps you..

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
label {
  display: block
}
select {
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Select:</label>
  <select>
    <option>*</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Select:</label>
  <select>
    <option>*</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Also Try this using bootstrap:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>The .dropdown class is used to indicate a dropdown menu.</p>
  <p>Use the .dropdown-menu class to actually build the dropdown menu.</p>
  <p>To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown".</p>                                          
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```